# Having troubles formatting scanf while keeping my code understandable

Tags: c

I need a function to read a file name, with a max length of `MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE`, which is a symbolic constant, I did this the following way:

```
char * readFileName()
{
    char format[6];

    char * fileName = malloc(MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE * sizeof(fileName[0]));

    if(fileName== NULL)
        return NULL;

    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE-1);
    scanf(format, fileName);

    fileName= realloc(fileName, strlen(fileName)*sizeof(fileName[0]));

    return fileName;
}
```

I'd really like to get read of the `sprintf` part (and also the `format` vector), what's the cleanest and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: See [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/) for one place where this is advocated as a method — citing [The Practice of Programming](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/tpop.webpage/) as a source for the technique.  If the size if truly fixed, then the `sprintf()` isn't so necessary, but if the sizes of the strings can vary, then it is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

You can make a little Preprocessor hack:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER  30
#define FORMAT(s)   "%" #s "s"
#define FMT(s)      FORMAT(s)

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];

    scanf(FMT(MAX_BUFFER), buffer);

    printf("string: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("length: %d\n", strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}
```

The `FORMAT` and `FMT` macros are necessary for the preprocessor to translate them correctly. If you call `FORMAT` directly with `FORMAT(MAX_BUFFER)`, it will translate into `"%" "MAX_BUFFER" "s"` which is no good.

You can verify that using `gcc -E scanf.c`. However, if you call it through another macro, which will effectively resolve the macro names for you and translate to `"%" "30" "s"`, which is a fine format string for `scanf`.

---

### Edit

As correctly pointed out by [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the comments, you can't do any math on that macro, so you need to declare `buffer` with plus 1 character for the NULL terminating byte, since the macro expands to `%30s`, which will read 30 characters plus the null byte.

So the correct buffer declaration should be `char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];`.

---

### Requested Explanation

As asked in the comments, the one macro version won't work because the preprocessor operator `#` turns an argument into a string (stringification, see bellow). So, when you call it with `FORMAT(MAX_BUFFER)`, it just stringifies `MAX_BUFFER` instead of macro-expanding it, giving you the result: `"%" "MAX_BUFFER" "s"`.

Section [3.4 Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)  of the C Preprocessor Manual says this:

> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you can use the `‘#’` preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter is used with a leading `‘#’`, the preprocessor replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant. **Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first.** This is called stringification.

This is the output of the `gcc -E scanf.c` command on a file with the one macro version (the last part of it):

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[30 + 1];

    scanf("%" "MAX_BUFFER" "s", buffer);

    printf("string: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("length: %d\n", strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}
```

As expected. Now, for the two levels, I couldn't explain better than the documentation itself, and in the last part of it there's an actual example of this specific case (two macros):

> If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, **you have to use two levels of macros**.

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

> `s` is stringified when it is used in `str`, so it is not macro-expanded first. **But `s` is an ordinary argument to `xstr`, so it is completely macro-expanded before `xstr` itself is expanded** (see [Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan)). Therefore, by the time `str` gets to its argument, *it has already been macro-expanded*.

---

### Resource

- [The C Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

Comment: This can work, with some caveats.  One of the caveats is that the array size needs to be `MAX_BUFFER+1` because the length specified in `scanf()` is the length without the null terminator.  Another is that the parameter to the macro must be a simple number; it cannot be an expression (so `MAX_BUFFER-1` is not OK).  However, if these are dealt with (which means that the first issue needs to be addressed in the answer), then this works for a fixed-size input.  If the size can vary, the `sprintf()` solution from the question is the best choice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I didn't pay attention to that. Edited.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand why the two macros method works, but not with a single macro, could you please explain it a bit more in detail?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Please check my last edit. I added a full explanation and manual reference.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Does that solve your problem and clear your doubts?

Comment: Ohhh I get it, thanks a lot Enzo! Very nice explanation.